# Logstash connecting to JBoss queue causing "AMQ119031 Unable to validate user"

Tags: jboss, jms, logstash, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to connect to a remote queue on JBoss EAP 7.1 with logstash. I've already made an application user and gave him the `guest` role using `add-user.sh` but whenever I try connecting to the queue I get a `AMQ119031 Unable to validate user` error here my settings from `logstash.conf`:

```
input {
    jms {
        # Logstash Configuration Settings. 
        include_header => false
        include_properties => false
        include_body => true
        use_jms_timestamp => false
        destination => "AuditTrailMDB"
        pub_sub => false
        # JNDI Settings
        jndi_name => 'jms/RemoteConnectionFactory'
        jndi_context => { 
            'java.naming.factory.initial' => org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory
            'java.naming.security.principal' => 'admin'
            'java.naming.provider.url' => 'http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080'
            'java.naming.security.credentials' => 'admin'
        }
        # Jar files to be imported
        require_jars=> ['/home/Alternant/logstash/dependencies/wildfly-client-all-7.1.0.GA-redhat-11.jar']
    }
 } 

 output {
     stdout{}
 }
```

`standalone.xml`:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
    <server name="default">
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <remote-connector name="netty" socket-binding="remote-messaging"/>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <remote-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-queue name="clientPending" entries="queue/clientPending"/>
        <jms-queue name="AuditTrailMDB" entries="queue/AuditTrailMDB java:jboss/exported/AuditTrailMDB"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <connection-factory name="ApplicationsQueueConnectionFactory" entries="/ApplicationsQueueConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

And for the log

```
[main] JMS Consumer Died {:exception=>"Java::JavaxJms::JMSSecurityException", :exception_message=>"AMQ119031: Unable to validate user", :backtrace=>["org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/protocol/core/impl/ChannelImpl.java:404)", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/protocol/core/impl/ChannelImpl.java:315)", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.createSessionContext(org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/protocol/core/impl/ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:288)", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.createSessionContext(org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/protocol/core/impl/ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:237)", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionChannel(org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/client/impl/ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1284)", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionInternal(org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/client/impl/ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:670)", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSession(org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/client/impl/ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:295)", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection.authorize(org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/client/ActiveMQConnection.java:671)", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/client/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:791)", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/client/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:265)", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/client/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:260)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:498)", "org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:440)"
```

JBoss log :

```
12:09:17,956 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (default I/O-3) AMQ224018: Failed to create session: ActiveMQSecurityException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=AMQ119031: Unable to validate user]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.security.impl.SecurityStoreImpl.authenticate(SecurityStoreImpl.java:144)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.createSession(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1283)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQPacketHandler.handleCreateSession(ActiveMQPacketHandler.java:158)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQPacketHandler.handlePacket(ActiveMQPacketHandler.java:81)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.handlePacket(ChannelImpl.java:633)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.doBufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:362)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:621)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:69)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at org.xnio.netty.transport.AbstractXnioSocketChannel$ReadListener.handleEvent(AbstractXnioSocketChannel.java:443)
    at org.xnio.netty.transport.AbstractXnioSocketChannel$ReadListener.handleEvent(AbstractXnioSocketChannel.java:379)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
```

Comment: Oh yeah sorry for that i will fix it

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing any credentials for JMS. You *are* passing credentials for the JNDI lookup, but keep in mind that JNDI and JMS are 100% independent of each other and therefore have their own credentials. You should be setting `username` and `password` in your `jms` block in `logstash.conf` as outlined in the [Logstash documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jms.html), e.g.:

```
jms {
    # Logstash Configuration Settings. 
    include_header => false
    include_properties => false
    include_body => true
    use_jms_timestamp => false
    destination => "AuditTrailMDB"
    pub_sub => false
    # JMS provider credentials
    username => "admin"
    password => "admin"
    # JNDI Settings
    jndi_name => 'jms/RemoteConnectionFactory'
    jndi_context => { 
        'java.naming.factory.initial' => org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory
        'java.naming.security.principal' => 'admin'
        'java.naming.provider.url' => 'http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080'
        'java.naming.security.credentials' => 'admin'
    }
    # Jar files to be imported
    require_jars=> ['/home/Alternant/logstash/dependencies/wildfly-client-all-7.1.0.GA-redhat-11.jar']
}
```

To be clear, this example config is just an example. You should adjust it to use the proper credentials for your environment.

Comment: Ok but in the Config for the jndi connection they didn't mention a username and password attributes ?
Oh and for the records that didn't work same exception, is there a default user in jms or should i create one and how ?

Comment: As someone who writes documentation occasionally I can readily say that just because the example in the documentation doesn't have it doesn't mean you don't need it. Is the authentication failure logged on the server? If so, did the log message change when you changed to the Logstash config to use JMS credentials? In your question you already said you created an application user, right? If that's correct then you should be using those credentials.

Comment: is the authentication failure logged on the server? yes,
 did the log message change when you changed to the Logstash config to use JMS credentials? no,
i'am using those credentials for both jms and jndi

Comment: So what message is logged on the server when authentication fails now?

Comment: Ok i will update the question with the JBoss logged exception

Comment: I didn't realize that JBoss EAP used such an old version of ActiveMQ Artemis. It's using version 1.5.5 which was released over 3 years ago now. It doesn't have the changes from [ARTEMIS-1306](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1306) to indicate which user caused the authentication failure. Therefore the server log doesn't really help unfortunately. JBoss EAP 7.2 uses ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6.3 which is much more up-to-date. Upgrading would be advisable.

Comment: Aside from upgrading in order to get more information about the error you can work-around the issue by disabling JMS security using `<security enabled="false" />` in the messaging subsystem configuration.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Comment: yes it was a miss configuration of the logstash config file, in order to pass the credentials we have to put the jndi properties in the yaml config file with the username and password.